# Saving session data and post it to database

Tags: php, sql, database, session, post

I have a site where you can order some tickets. If someone makes an order, I want the order to be send to the database. Also I want to put the specific cart items in to be send to the database. See the model I use:

```
ORDERS              CART ITEMS

id*                 id
amount              order_id*
                    product_id
                    quantity
```

This is the code I use with the form:

```
<form action="index.php?page=cart" method="post" class="">
    <table class=" table__nav">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="p p--bold p--th th--ticket">Ticket</th>
                <th class="p p--bold p--th th--name">Name</th>
                <th class="p p--bold p--th th--quantity">Quantity</th>
                <th class="p p--bold p--th th--price">Price per ticket</th>


                <th class="p p--bold p--th th--itemtotal">Item Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        $total = 0;
        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $ticket) {
            $ticketTotal = $ticket['ticket']['price'] * $ticket['quantity'];
            $total += $ticketTotal;
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $ticket['ticket']['eye_cart']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class = "p--bold"><?php echo $ticket['ticket']['name']; ?></p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class = "p td--quantity" type="number" name="quantity[<?php echo $ticket['ticket']['id'];?>]" value="<?php echo $ticket['quantity'];?>" class="replace" required />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>&#8364;<?php echo $ticket['ticket']['price'];?>,-</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>&#8364;<?php echo $ticketTotal;?>,-</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                <td class="remove-item"><button type="submit" class="btn remove-from-cart" name="remove" value="<?php echo $ticket['ticket']['id'];?>">&#215;</button></td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>

    <div class="table__wrap">
        <button type="submit" id="update-cart" class="btn btn--cart" name="action" value="update">
            <img width="14" height="14" src="./assets/img/refresh.png" alt="refresh">
        </button>
        </img>
        <p class="table__order--total"><span class="span--bold span--bold-no">Total:</span></p>
        <p class="table__order--number"><span class="span--bold span--bold-no">&#8364; <?php echo $total ?>,-</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="table__wrap table__wrap--end">
        <a class="p p__li p__li--light" href="index.php?page=register"> 
            <button type = "submit" name ="action" value = "details" class="btn btn--big btn--big-2 btn--dark">your details -> </button></a>
    </div>
</form>
```

When the user presses the button to go to `"your details"` I want to save an order with the total amount + the cart items with the order_id and quantity.

I'm using the `MVC` model for this but I can't really figure it out.

This is how my controller looks:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'details') {
  $data =  array(
    'amount' => $total,
  );
  $insertedOrder = $this->orderDAO->insertOrder($data);
  $this->set('insertedOrder', $insertedOrder);

  if (empty($insertedOrder)) {
    $errors = $this->orderDAO->validate($data);
    $this->set('errors', $errors);
    }
  }
  if ($_POST['action'] == 'details') {
  $dataB=  array(
    'order_id' => ?,
    'product_id' => $_SESSION['cart']['id']['ticket']['id'],
    'quantity' => $_SESSION['cart']['quantity'],
  );
  $insertedCartItem = $this->orderDAO->insertCartItem($data);
  $this->set('insertedCartItem', $insertedCartItem);

  if (empty($insertedCartItem)) {
    $errors = $this->orderDAO->validateB($dataB);
    $this->set('errors', $errors);
    }
  }
```

And the next code is my DAO:

```
public function insertOrder($data){
    $errors = $this->validate( $data );
    if (empty($errors)) {
      $sql = "INSERT INTO `orders` (`amount`) VALUES (:amount)";
      $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindValue(':amount', $data['amount']);
      if ($stmt->execute()) {
        return $this->selectOrderById($this->pdo->lastInsertId());
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  public function insertCartItem($dataB){
    $errors = $this->validateB($dataB);
    if (empty($errors)) {
      $sql = "INSERT INTO `cart_items` (`order_id` `product_id`,`quantity`) VALUES (:order_id, :product_id, :quantity)";
      $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindValue(':order_id', $dataB['order_id']);
      $stmt->bindValue(':product_id', $dataB['product_id']);
      $stmt->bindValue(':quantity', $dataB['quantity']);
      if ($stmt->execute()) {
        return $this->selectCartItemById($this->pdo->lastInsertId());
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

The main problem I have is that I don't know how I can send data from $_SESSION variables to the database. I run into problems in the controller. As you can see I'm sending data with the $data and $dataB, but I think I'm going wrong there.

Comment: That is a pretty broad question. Are you encountering any errors? Are you checking your logs? What specifically are you stuck on? Narrow it down a little.

Comment: use opencart :)

Comment: @ficuscr see edit

Comment: The code for your inserts seems sane at first glance. Does it work? If it doesn't you should get an error saying why not. Speculation is a waste of time. I still use `var_dump` all the time. Does `var_dump($dataB)` contain what you expect?

Comment: Nope it doesn't. From $data; $total is undefined. From $datab only quantity is right. @ficuscr

Comment: OK, so debug why. Is it in the `$_POST`? If not we know we need to step back and look at the form submit. If it's in the POST, then why is it not making it into your `$data` array?

Comment: $_POST is empty.. @ficuscr

Comment: OK, now you are back debugging in the browser with "developer tools". Why is nothing POSTed by your form? Your code doesn't show where `$total` is ever assigned a value...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194463/discussion-between-foxonfirehd-and-ficuscr).